# How to get value of POST variables using JS for update with php mysql?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to update my table, and i have script in php page on my server for getting value like this

```
<div ng-controller="customersCrtl">
  <div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="update_mul.php">
      <td><input type="hidden" name="Id[]" value="{{data.Id}}" />{{data.Region}}</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="sii[]" value="{{data.Site_ID_Implementation}}"/></td>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my update page is

```
<?php
    include_once 'connect.php';
    $id = $_POST['Id'];
    $sii = $_POST['sii'];
    $chkcount = count($id);
    for($i=0; $i<$chkcount; $i++)
    {
        echo $mysqli->query("UPDATE WS_Manado SET Site_ID_Implementation = '".$sii[$i]."'
                                        WHERE Id=".$id[$i]);
    }
?>
```

But this doesn't work, no error messagese or other just back to first page
Firstly if i use `<?php echo $row['Site_ID_Implementation'];?>` on value, it's working

**UPDATE**
app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        if(input) {
            start = +start; //parse to int
            return input.slice(start);
        }
        return [];
    }
});
app.controller('customersCrtl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $http.get('ajax/getCustomers.php').success(function(data){
        $scope.list = data;
        $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
        $scope.entryLimit = 100; //max no of items to display in a page
        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter  
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;
    });
    $scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
        $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
    };
    $scope.filter = function() {
        $timeout(function() { 
            $scope.filteredItems = $scope.filtered.length;
        }, 10);
    };
    $scope.sort_by = function(predicate) {
        $scope.predicate = predicate;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };
});
```

getCustomers.php

```
<?php
include('../connect.php');

$query="select distinct c.Region,c.Category,c.Site_ID_Implementation from WS_Manado c order by c.Id";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

$arr = array();
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $arr[] = $row;  
    }
}
# JSON-encode the response
$json_response = json_encode($arr);

// # Return the response
echo $json_response;
?>
```

Comment: all right before you access $_POST[], you should first check whether it is set. you can do so by saying if ( isset($_POST['Id']) ) { $id = $_POST['Id'] }

Comment: learn about it more http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: convert  `Id[]` to `Id` and  `sii[]` to `sii`

Comment: You tag `javascript`, and have `JS` in your title, but I don't see any javascript code here. Are you posting your form using javascript? If yes, add the code. If no, then remove these.

Comment: @Sean   
ok but query is checking 0th record i think its not exist in db

Comment: @Amruthls no, it is checking `0` key in the array -> `$id[0]`, which is different than the 0th record.

Comment: @Sean ya its fine

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.